# How can i change the background of jQuery UI dialog

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

i took the div of the jQuery UI and added some CSS to change the background but it looks like it DOESN'T"T change the bottom section where the buttons are. See screenshot below.  As you can see the main part of the dialog in this case changes to grey background but not the bottom part.

Is there anyway to change the bottom part as well as people keep thinking there is no button to close the dialog as it kind of blends into the background.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this in your css

```
.ui-dialog-content{
background:grey !important;
}

.ui-dialog-buttonpane{
background:white !important;
}
```

### Check Working example at http://jsfiddle.net/2z8Hd/1/